# C - Matrix > Only Positive Elements

Tags: c, matrix, input

I need your help, code which i will show you is just a beginning, but i already have a problem as a beginner, so please help me, i don't think it will be hard for them who knows C.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    int matrix[10][10];
    int nrows, ncols, i, j, chosen;

    printf("Enter number of rows: "); //user enters number of rows
    scanf("%d", &nrows);
    if(nrows < 2){
        printf("\n Out of range, please try again");
        exit(5);
    }
    printf("Enter number of columns: "); //user enters number of columns
    scanf("%d", &ncols);
    if(ncols < 2){
        printf("\n Out of range, please try again");
        exit(5);
    }

    printf("Enter matrix elements: "); //user enters all the elements for Matrix
                for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
                    for(j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
                        scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            printf("This is your matrix: \n");
                for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
                    for(j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
                        printf("%d \t",matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }

    return 0;

}
```

Nothing special, user enters number of rows and columns and later fills up this matrix with elements.

Now the problem, right now user can enter any kind of integer, positive and negative, ***i just want to limit user so that he/she could enter only positive numbers.***

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Tried to create new variable and assign all the elements to it, tried do/while, for and if/else but i don't think that i make it in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you tried to use another variable and 'while' loop, so you can do it like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
   for(j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
      tmp=0;
      scanf("%d",&tmp);
      while(tmp<0){
          printf("enter positive numbers only\n");
          scanf("%d",&tmp);
      }
      matrix[i][j]=tmp;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another huge pitfall you have fallen into is failure to check the return of `scanf`. `scanf` is notoriously problematic for new C programmers to handle appropriately because of the subtle differences in how the various *format specifiers* handle leading whitespace, and characters that remain in `stdin` after input is taken.

At minimum, you must check the return and **validate** the number of conversion expected did in fact take place, that `EOF` was not returned indicating that the user canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze). You must also empty any characters that remain in `stdin` following an error and following successful conversion if character input can follow (the trailing `'\n'` remains unread).

Another style nit is to space your code a little more broadly. Young eyes may have no problems with all characters mushed together, but for the rest of the world, proper spacing makes code much more readable.

Putting those pieces together, and putting the reading of an `int` and emptying `stdin` into functions so you avoid repeated blocks of code, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** simple function to empty all characters that remain
 *  in stdin. Needed when using scanf for user input.
 */
void empty_stdin()
{
    for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
}

/** abbreviated function to read integer value from user.
 *  returns value on success, exits if user cancels.
 *  empties stdin after call to scanf.
 */
int getint ()
{
    int n = 0,
        rtn = 0;        /* variable to capture return of scanf */

    if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &n)) == EOF) {  /* if user cancels, exit */
        fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();      /* empty all chars remaining in stdin */

    return n;
}

int main (void) 
{
    int matrix[10][10] = {{0}};
    int nrows, ncols, i, j;

    printf ("Enter number of rows: ");
    nrows = getint();
    if (nrows < 2) {
        printf ("\n Out of range, please try again");
        return 5;
    }
    printf ("Enter number of columns: ");
    ncols = getint();;
    if (ncols < 2) {
        printf ("\n Out of range, please try again");
        return 5;
    }

    printf ("\nEnter matrix elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            printf ("  matrix[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            matrix[i][j] = getint();
        }

    printf ("\nThis is your matrix: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
            printf (" %3d", matrix[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/matrixscanf
Enter number of rows: 3
Enter number of columns: 3

Enter matrix elements
  matrix[0][0]: 1
  matrix[0][1]: 2
  matrix[0][2]: 3
  matrix[1][0]: 4
  matrix[1][1]: 5
  matrix[1][2]: 6
  matrix[2][0]: 7
  matrix[2][1]: 8
  matrix[2][2]: 9

This is your matrix:
   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.